# Creating a text,value pair using dictionary in python or reactjs

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs

I have a dictionary of the form as follows:

```
dict={"text":10,"textg":31,"textf":23}
```

I want this to be converted as follows:

```
newlist=[{
text:"text",
value:10
},
{
text:"textg",
value:31
},
{
text:"textf",
value:23
}
]
```

Is there any possible way to do it in python or reactjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
dic={"text":10,"textg":31,"textf":23}
newlist = [{"text": key, "value": val} for key, val in dic.items()]
print(newlist)
```

> Output:

```
[{'text': 'text', 'value': 10}, {'text': 'textg', 'value': 31}, {'text': 'textf', 'value': 23}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to make `newList`:

```py
dict={"text":10,"textg":31,"textf":23}
newList= []

for item, value in dict.items():
    newList.append({"text": item, "value": value})
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can iterate over a dictionary in many ways, to get its key and value you can use `dict.items()`
Here is a function that would do what you want

```py
def to_list(d):
    l = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        l.append({"text":k, "value":v})
    return l
```

Or, if you prefer list comprehensions:

```py
def to_list(d):
    return [{"text":k, "value":v} for k,v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind what you want to do is that you do not realize that a dictionary can be an item in a list. A list can take any data structure as item.
Here is a little code that does what you want.

```
mydict = {'text':10, 'textg': 31, 'textf': 23}
newlist = []
# collect the keys into a list so you can accecss them
dict_keys = [ keys for keys in mydict.keys()]
for keys in dict_keys:
    #create new dictionary instance for each
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict['text'] = keys
    new_dict['value'] = mydict[keys]
    newlist.append(new_dict)

print(newlist)
```